# Access Java RMI from .NET

Tags: java, .net, rmi

I have a existing java based system which uses RMI.  I do not have access to change this system.

I want to be able to call the RMI api methods directly from .NET.  What is the best way to accomplish this?  Free or lowish cost preferred if its a third party component.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet would be to build a Java facade for the existing system which will talk with it using RMI and on the other side provide something more standard - Web Services or maybe REST.

Additional advantage of this approach is the protection it gives you against the legacy app bugs and bad design decisions. For example, if there are some ugly workarounds that you need to do to call the existing application, those can be safely hidden in the facade layer without compromising the desing and integrity of the new app you are writing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about .Net + RMI.  However it should be possible to build a Java component which talks to the RMI service and call that Java component from .Net using one of the supported mechanisms.

Article about calling Java from .Net

- http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/daniel-at-work/using-ikvm-to-call-java-from-net-21993

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access the EJB using CORBA

Look here: http://weblogic.sys-con.com/node/42640
Old but quite relevant.

Comment: How do you know that it's an EJB exported by CORBA ?